# Enable syntax highlighting in iTerm2 or nano?

Tags: c, iterm2, nano

My query today is how exactly I would go about enabling some basic syntax highlighting in nano when I use it on iTerm2. I've seen some suggestions regarding switching to zsh terminal, but was wondering if there was a simpler way.

Also, in my search it has been unclear if one should alter syntax highlighting in iTerm or in nano itself somehow. For clarification I am using nano to write c files.

Thank you to all who reply.

Answer (score 0):

You need syntax highlighting for `nano` as that is the thing that actually knows what the words on the screen mean. `iterm2` just needs to support showing the colors (which it does out of the box).

A fast google search reveals this repo https://github.com/scopatz/nanorc, which claims to have syntax highlighting for nano. I do not use nano, however, so I can't say how to install it, or if it really works.